# glide placeholder not showing image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

android glide not showing the fetched image. its stuck at default image. am using glide version 4.7.1 here is my code bellow

```
 mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

 mAuthUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
 userIDM = mAuthUser.getCurrentUser().getUid();

 //getting data from firebaseFireStore
 firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userIDM).get().addOnCompleteListener(new
 OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()){

             Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             if (task.getResult().exists()){

                 Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "user data exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  String name = task.getResult().getString("name");
                  String image = task.getResult().getString("image");

                 RequestOptions placeHolder = new RequestOptions();
                 placeHolder.placeholder(R.mipmap.setup_user);

                 userName.setText(name);
                 Glide
                         .with(SetupActivity.this)
                         .setDefaultRequestOptions(placeHolder)
                         .load(image)
                         .into(userImage);

             }else {
                 Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "user data dose'nt exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }

         }else {

             String errorM = task.getException().getMessage();
             Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"error"+errorM, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a empty class like this

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

// new since Glide v4
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
```

now use Glide like this :

```
GlideApp.with(SetupActivity.this)
.load(image)
.placeholder(R.mipmap.setup_user)
.into(userImage);
```

Comment: getting error  like :.... *** { cannot resolve method 'apply(com.bumptech.glide.request.Request option)'  }

Glide
  .with(SetupActivity.this)
  .apply(placeHolder) ......****
  .load(image)
  .into(userImage);

Comment: which version of Glide are you using?

Comment: am using 4.7.1

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

Comment: follow this link for [Glide 4.7.1](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library) please read the instruction carefully and follow the steps

Comment: getting error please check i had attached screen shoot links bellow
http://i.imgur.com/wazszuh.png
https://i.imgur.com/JH75i7Ll.png

Comment: Just rebuild your project it will work and use RequestOption object and pass it into `.setDefaultRequestOptions(placeHolder)`

Comment: solved it after downgrading the Glide version and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();
                        placeholderRequest.placeholder(drawable img you want);

                        Glide.with(SetupActivity.this).setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest).load(ur variable).into(ur vraiable);
```

Answer (score 0):

In glide add 
  .placeholder(yourimage)
 it works

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(context)
           .load(your img url)
           .into(your image place)
           .onLoadStarted(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image,null))
```

in newer versions

Comment: Try to explain your answer. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the Glide version works for me. You can give it a try.